# Error on using "reset" command in "terminal tool window" of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, intellij-idea, terminal

I use `Android Studio 2.2.2` on `Ubuntu 14.04`. I can run `Android Studio` by running `studio.sh` in terminal. But when I run `reset` command in `Terminal tool window` of `Android Studio` I saw this error in terminal (which `Android Studio` is running in that):

```
[130270931]  ERROR - terminal.emulator.JediEmulator - Unhandled Control sequence
parsed                        :ESC[p
bytes read                    :ESC[ 
[130270931]  ERROR - jediterm.terminal.TerminalMode - Mode InsertMode is not implemented, setting to false
```

What the meaning of that error and how I can solve that?

Edit:

As @Thomas Dickey  said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41307601/1043882), the value of `$TERM` was `xterm-256color`. So I changes it's value by `TERM=vt100`, but when run `reset` again, I got another error:

```
[ 282356]  ERROR - jediterm.terminal.TerminalMode - Mode SmoothScroll is not implemented, setting to false 
[ 282356]  ERROR - jediterm.terminal.TerminalMode - Mode ReverseVideo is not implemented, setting to false 
[ 282357]  ERROR - jediterm.terminal.TerminalMode - Mode AutoRepeatKeys is not implemented, setting to true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is telling you that `terminal.emulator.JediEmulator` does not implement a standard control sequence (you might say "escape sequence", but that's less general).

The [`reset` command](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html#h3-reset---reinitialization) is sending among other things this sequence: <kbd>*escape*</kbd><kbd>`[`</kbd><kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`l`</kbd>.  As you might guess from the warning message, the terminal emulator does not support that.  It comes from the terminal description for xterm, in the **`rs2`** capability.

Very likely your shell sets `TERM` to `xterm`.  Although the feature was supported in vt100, the terminal description for it does not use that feature (the reason is that for vt100, `reset` will do the equivalent of a power-up initialization while that for xterm uses a less drastic approach).

You *could* set `TERM` to `vt100`, but then would lose color on applications that aren't hardcoded (since as everyone knows, [vt100s never did do color](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color)).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited my question. Please see it again.

Comment: From that, it seems that your Android Studio terminal emulator is mostly to-do items.